# Nodes of a list being freed before usage

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have a one-dimensional template list that contains nodes, each node has a link to next node.
It works rather well on it's own, but not when it contains another linked list.

LinkedList and Node looks something like that:

```
template <class T> 
class LinkedList 
{ 
    private:
        Node<T>* pPreHead; 
    public:
        LinkedList(void);
        ~LinkedList(void);
        Node<T>* getHead(void);
        int size();
        void addElementToEnd(T& value);
        void deleteNextNode(Node<T>* pNodeBefore);
}

template <class T>
class Node 
{
    private:
        T value;
        Node* next;
    public:
        Node();
        Node* getNext();
        Node* getValue();
        void setNext(Node* nextElem);
        void setValue(T elem);
};
```

Now for the task I need to use LinkedList>, which is filled via a loop.
It looks something like this:

```
ifstream fl;
fl.open("test1.in", std::ifstream::in);
while (fl.good())
{
    string currentLine;
    getline(fl, currentLine);

    LinkedList<string> newDNA;

    //newDNA being filled here so I skipped code

    DNAStorage.addElementToEnd(newDNA);

    //Place 1
}

//Place 2
```

Now if I insert some test output code in "Place 1" everything is fine, but when the loop enters new iteration `newDNA` variable gets freed and so is the pointer inside `DNAStorage` (which is `LinkedList<LinkedList<string>>` in question), and when I try to print anything in "Place 2" I get segmentation fault.

Unfortunately I can't use any other data structures since this is the kind of task I need to do.
My question is - how can this be fixed, so that it actually is not freed prematurely?

Edit:
Here's my code for `AddElementToEnd(T& value)`:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::addElementToEnd(T &value)
{
    Node<T> *newtail = new Node<T>;
    newtail.setNext(NULL);
    newtail.setValue(value);

    if(pPreHead == NULL)
    {
        pPreHead = newtail;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *tail = pPreHead;
    while(tail.getNext() != NULL)
    {
        tail = tail.getNext();
    }

    tail.setNext(newtail);
}
```

Comment: Either allocate it dynamically or don't store pointers. Prefer the latter. BTW your file-reading loop is wrong: you do not check the result of `getline`.

Comment: Yes, I know about checking `getline` - I skipped a lot of code specific for my task where I need to fill `newDNA`.
About not storing pointers - can you please explain that? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: You said that `DNAStorage` stores a pointer to `newDNA`. Simply don't do that. Store it by copying/moving. Unfortunately we have no idea what `DNAStorage` or `LinkedList` do so I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Updated the opening post with prototypes of `LinkedList<T>` and `Node<T>`
Lists store only a pointer to the head of Node chain.

Comment: If you want to post the code you have for `addElementToEnd(T& value)`, that will make it quite clear.

Comment: You should post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), actually. Not little snippets.

Comment: @Joel: Added my code into the opening post.
Lightness: Will do in a second

Comment: @Testie `LinkedList<string> newDNA;`  This is a local variable to the block.  When that block exits, the destructor is called.  Thus you need to post the destructor, as your "Place 2 " is where you identified a problem.  As a matter of fact, since it's local to the `while` loop, a new LinkedList is created on each iteration, with the previous instance being destroyed.  So there is a lot more to the code than just an "add" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing references to objects that are going out of scope, causing undefined behavior when you try and access them.  Your `LinkedList<string> newDNA` gets created and destroyed with each iteration of the while loop, yet you pass a reference to be stored in `DNAStorage` list.

One solution would be to store a copy of each object (not reference) in the list when `addElementToEnd()` gets called.

Comment: The code is ok *if* the copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator are working properly.   The reference doesn't matter, as I would hope that `setValue` creates the copy by using the copy constructor or assignment operator for `LinkedList`

Comment: Sure. Implementing those would be a good solution. I was just trying to explain why the current code caused undefined behavior the way it currently is.